# Entity Framework - A relationship is in the 'Deleted' state error occurs randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So I have gone through all the "A relationship from the 'XXX_XXX' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state" questions and answers on here, but I have not been able to figure out my problem...

The web application that I am maintaining has been up and running for about 1-2 years.  Just recently (within the last month or two), random users have called in about getting a meesage of "An unhandle error occured".  After looking through the error logs, we found that these individuals are getting the following error just like in the other posts:

> A relationship from the 'User_Metrics' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'User_Metrics_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

Now comes the weird issue... If they switch the computer they are using to log in to the application, another computer in the same office, the error does not occur again and the application runs fine for them on the new system.  If they go back to the previous system (after clearing cache, cookies, etc) they again have the error.  So I am leaning towards it being system specific setting since this issue hasn't happened before...

Tha application is using: Entity Framwork, .Net Framwork 4, C#, ASP.Net MVC, KendoUI, Durandal .... I believe that is it.

Does anyone know if some sort of change to a particular setting on the actual computer can cause this?

Thanks, Nick